How to make microphone suppress the audio that sounds from speakers at the moment on iPhone?
I was implemented ChatGPT Real-time API, that allows to chat with bot in real time with a voice among other methods. But I've faced a problem that ChatGPT always starts talking with itself when using loud speakers (.defaultToSpeaker). It works well with headphones and telephone speakers.
I've tried to use volume-based filter for speakers output, but it has approximately the same loudness that users' voices, so it didn't work even when I used .voiceChat mode.
Adding .duckOthers helped me in case with telephone speakers, but it didn't do with .defaultToSpeaker.
Along with that original OpenAI's application works well even with loud speakers. My current session setting is as following:
try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.defaultToSpeaker, .duckOthers, .allowBluetooth]) 
try audioSession.setActive(true)

Can you suggest me solution to cut-off speakers audio from microphone input?

Why not just mute the mic while the machine is talking?

Because I need to add possibility to interrupt bot to end user.l
